# Require Specific Bundle Workflow for a Given Schema

Tags: 2013, workflow, bundles

Schemas can have a preferred multi-item workflow in SDL Tridion. I understand this becomes a default in XPM, but authors can choose other bundles in the CM.

To force a given schema (e.g. "Global Footer") through only one bundle workflow option, we could:

1. Use "legacy" single-item workflow
2. Use permissions to limit access to either the bundle or bundle schema for certain authors
3. Change other workflow process definitions to handle this schema

If the preference is to avoid the Legacy Pack, what would be a reasonable implementation? Would you consider Event System code to place items based on this schema in a specific bundle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single-item workflow though is the old style approach and might be termed legacy, however, is not part of legacy pack. It is a kernel feature. What is part of legacy pack in the VBScript type of automated activity script. That being said, I would still be not in favor of using a single-item workflow. A combination of permissions and event system might be a more concrete approach. Permissions can be used to limit access and to ensure that it is followed, and no gaps are present a event handler could be created for `AddToWorkflowEventArgs` in `Processed` to ensure that the item(s) being added to workflow is using the appropriate process definition.

Or an event handler could be created on Bundle save to ensure that the items in it are all using the same preferred multi-item process definition as well as the bundle itself.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification that the Legacy Pack allows VBScript rather than single-item workflow. I like the flexibility in using authorization along with the event system.